# Handling Loop And Array in Jmeter + Groovy - Response code 500

Tags: arrays, loops, groovy, jmeter

I am trying to create a script that perform a loop, and fill array with Http results.
the expected results is array with passwords, with the size of the loop (in the example 3).
The problem is that in each iteration of the loop it is not familiar with the array that I created in the first iteration of the loop.
Can someone please advise how to fill an array inside a loop in Jmeter?
Or how to solve this issue? any example will be  great

res_g1 - is the value that I want to enter to each place in the array, meanning a password.
Password - is the array that I would like to feel with data
loop counter - counts the iteration of the loop 1,2,3

```
def loop_counter = ${__counter(TRUE)};
def results = vars.get('res_g1')
if (loop_counter == 1)
{
    def  Password = new String[3];
    System.out.println("Entered the loop");
}

Password[loop_counter -1] = vars.get('res_g1');
System.out.println("loop number is :  " + loop_counter + " Password is" + results );
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: not clear what you try to do. the error `No such property Password for class Scrit...` means that you try to access variable and it's not declared. The `def Password` disappears just after `if (loop_counter == 1){ ... }`

Comment: Hello, any feedback on answer ? If ok it should be marked as OK and upvoted so that others can use it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it:

Use a [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) element inside loop:

[image]

Then use this script:

[image]

Pay attention to:

- Cache compiled script being checked for performances
- the storage of the array I want to fill as a Variable using vars.putObject(...)
- the vars.getObject(.) to get it back
- The use of Logger.info from SLF4J for logging instead of System.out.println